# Sending an email to myself using flask

Tags: python, flask

So I have been trying to create query form, so a customer can send a question to my email. After submitting a form I am getting an error message

> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

```
@phones.route('/contact', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():
form = ContactForm()
email = form.email.data
if request.method == 'POST':
if form.validate() == False:
  flash('All fields are required.')
  return render_template('phones/contact.html', form=form)
else:
  msg = Message(form.subject.data, sender='sameemail@gmail.com', 
recipients='sameemail@gmail.com')
  msg.body = """
  From: %s %s


  %s
  """ % (form.name.data, form.email.data, form.message.data)
  mail.send(msg)
  flash(f'Your email has been sent', 'success')  
  return redirect(url_for('main.index'))

elif request.method == 'GET':
return render_template('phones/contact.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
recipients=['sameemail@gmail.com']
```

It should do the job

Comment: msg.body doesn't cause an error, when i change the recipients to recipients=[email], so it sends the email to the one that was entered in the form it works, so the problem is with sending an email to myself

Comment: sorry, the just do this ``` 'sameemail@gmail.com' ```